# How to disagree with a Remark?

Tags: discussion, documentation

In the documentation for [ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net#t=201608141411083699991), [Executing SQL statements as a command](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/12379/executing-sql-statements-as-a-command#t=201608141412230956999) and [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements#t=201608141413040375697) there is a remark that *"AddWithValue is a good starting point and works fine in most cases"*.

This is inaccurate; it is a *bad* starting point because anyone who uses it may well have to go back and use less vague code in the future (i.e. `AddWithValue` introduces technical debt). It is even noted that it is a bad idea in the third of those examples.

I haven't seen anywhere to comment on remarks: should I edit the "Remarks" section to delete the incorrect information, or start an edit war with comments-as-remarks back-and-forth? Or is there a sensible third option available to me?

Comment: I made a change to the ADO.NET example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/84561)

Comment: @Drew The question is talking about the remarks section which still says "AddWithValue is a good starting point and works fine in most cases" - that is not good advice.

Comment: DavidG I fixed one code area. I was not suggesting I cleaned it all up. Others can take it from there.

Comment: I think a improvement request would do what you want if you don't actually wan to edit it yourself but let the docs community know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I haven't seen anywhere to comment on remarks: should I edit the
>   "Remarks" section to delete the incorrect information, or start an
>   edit war with comments-as-remarks back-and-forth? Or is there a
>   sensible third option available to me?

Documentation is collaborative editing. Any contribution can be modified or deleted at any point.

If you see something that is wrong on Documentation my first advice would be to edit it and correct it with a meaningful edit comment. This correction includes deleting wrong things and adding right things.

If you later discover that your edit has been replaced with wrong information again I would start a meta discussion about it right here or wait for tag/topic specific discussion areas which are requested but not yet implemented.

Finally, you could start a discussion about how to ensure high quality content. From Q&A or from Wikipedia like efforts we have probably some ideas of what could be done there or where the limits are. Like moderators could sanction bad behavior or edit reviews could be more strict for more mature content.